# D3 append based on header name

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is what my xScale is like:

```
  var fundTypes = ['Trust', 'BMWP', 'Pension', 'MMF'];

  var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(fundTypes)
      .range([0,width]);
```

For my yScale, I have:

```
  var yScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.date}))
      .range([height,0]);
```

And my data is like so:

```
var data = [
    {'Trust':7, 'BWMP':5, 'Pension':4, 'MMF':3, 'Date':'2019-07'},
    {'Trust':8, 'BWMP':5, 'Pension':3, 'MMF':2, 'Date':'2019-08'}
    ...
];
```

I want to create circles where `cx` is the `fundType` and `cy` is the `date`, however I can't find a way to tell d3 I mean to reference the column name. Attempt below:

```
  graphGroup.selectAll('circle')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', function(d) {return xScale(d.???????)})
```

### Question

How do I tell d3 I mean for the `cx` to be the header name itself?

Comment: Btw. when you define the `domain` in your yScale you use `d.date` (date is lower case) whereas in your `data` array the variable is `Date` (Date is capitalized). Might be a cause of an error at some point.

Comment: On top of the comment above, the scale's domain is incorrect: when using a time scale the domain must be **date** objects, not strings. I hope you're parsing those strings somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use your data with a `.selectAll` to create a circle for each fund, you need to convert your data into a structure, where there is a data entry for each fund.

First, your original data:

```
var data = [
  {'Trust':7, 'BWMP':5, 'Pension':4, 'MMF':3, 'Date':'2019-07'},
  {'Trust':8, 'BWMP':5, 'Pension':3, 'MMF':2, 'Date':'2019-08'}
];
```

We massage it to a different structure with an entry for each fund.

```
var circleData = data.map((fundCollection) => {
  return Object.keys(fundCollection).map((singleFund) => {
    return {
      fund: singleFund,
      count: fundCollection[singleFund],
      date: fundCollection.Date
    }
  }).filter((d) => {
    return d.fund !== 'Date'
  })
}).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return acc.concat(curr)
}, [])
```

The result is a data structure that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "fund": "Trust",
    "count": 7,
    "date": "2019-07"
  },
  {
    "fund": "BWMP",
    "count": 5,
    "date": "2019-07"
  },
  ...
]
```

Using the new data structure, you can insert circles for each fund type like this:

```
graphGroup.selectAll('circle')
  .data(circleData)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {return xScale(d.fund)})
  .attr('cy', function(d) {return yScale(d.date)})
```

Hope this helps!